# how to clearInterval if any previous setInterval is running in REACT?

Tags: reactjs, setinterval, clearinterval

I want to make a Reverse Countdown Timer in which that has an input field and when I type a number and press the "Enter" key, the countdown starts. but the problem is when I want to stop the previous interval and starts new interval with new number and press Enter key, it runs parallel with previous one.

I'm pretty new to react, can somebody give me some advice to fix the problem ?

```
import React, {useState} from "react";

const App = () => {

  const [ctime, setctime]=useState();
 
  const enterdown=(value)=>{

      clearInterval(interval);

      setctime(value);
      var interval =  setInterval(()=>{
        value--;
        if(value==0){
          clearInterval(interval);
        }
        setctime(value);
      },1000)
  }
  return (
    <div className="wrapper">
      <div id="whole-center">
        <h1>
          Reverse countdown for<input id="timeCount" onKeyDown={(e)=>{e.key == "Enter" ?(enterdown(e.target.value)) :null}} /> sec.
        </h1>
      </div>
      <div id="current-time">{ctime}</div>  
    </div>
  )
}


export default App;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this `const interval = useRef();` instead of `var interval`

Full working code:
Also codesandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-monad-thhrvz?file=/src/App.js

```
const App = () => {
  const interval = useRef();
  const [ctime, setctime] = useState();

  const enterdown = (value) => {
    clearInterval(interval.current);

    setctime(value);
    interval.current = setInterval(() => {
      value--;
      if (value == 0) {
        clearInterval(interval.current);
      }
      setctime(value);
    }, 1000);
  };
  return (
    <div className="wrapper">
      <div id="whole-center">
        <h1>
          Reverse countdown for
          <input
            id="timeCount"
            onKeyDown={(e) => {
              e.key == "Enter" ? enterdown(e.target.value) : null;
            }}
          />{" "}
          sec.
        </h1>
      </div>
      <div id="current-time">{ctime}</div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The `interval` variable gets created each time the `App` function is run.
Which is in this case each time you press Enter.
It can be fixed by placing it out of the App function.

```js
let interval;

const App = () => {
  const [ctime, setctime] = useState();

  const enterdown = (value) => {
    clearInterval(interval);

    setctime(value);
    interval = setInterval(() => {
      value--;
      if (value === 0) {
        clearInterval(interval);
      }
      setctime(value);
    }, 1000);
  };
// ...
```

Another solution would be using `useRef`